# How to strike out data in a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my project, I wish to strike a particular data if one of the cells in the data reads "Void" but when I did with the code I used all the data in the DataGridView was strike meaning accepting the first argument to all data despite some of the data in the said cells reads "Active".

Below is my code:

```
For Each r As DataGridViewRow In frmCheckOut_Room.DataGridView2.Rows
    If (r.Cells(9).Value) = "Void" Then
        r.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
        r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Strikeout)
    ElseIf (r.Cells(9).Value) = "Active" Then
        r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8)
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello
I use **CellFormatting** event of the grid to achieve this. For example:

```
 Private Sub DataGridView2_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellFormatting
    If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView2.Columns("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME").Index AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        If (e.Value = "Void") Then
            DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Strikeout)
            DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf (e.Value = "Active") Then
           DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8)
           DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I prefer to use column name instead of column index but if you wish you can replace `If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView2.Columns("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME").Index Then`

With:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 9 Then
```

I don't have chance to test it so if you have any problems or questions don't hesitate to message me. 

Regards

**EDIT:**
If you want to mark every cell in the grid that contains word "*Active*" or "*Void*" just use this code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellFormatting
If (e.Value.GetType() = GetType(String)) Then
    If (e.Value = "Void") Then
        DataGridView2(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Style.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Strikeout)
        DataGridView2(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf (e.Value = "Active") Then
       DataGridView2(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Style.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8)
       DataGridView2(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Same problem still persist

Comment: You want only specific cell to be Strikeout, not the entire row?